# Combo Estado e Bairro em AngularJS

Tags: angular

Tenho este método de Consulta dependente de Estado e Cidade.
consigo salvar e consultar.
Quando vou na na tela de atualizar,  tipo 'RJ / Angra dos reis', ele não aparece  na tela  se eu ir na tela e clicar em outro estado e depois voltar para o RJ, ai a cidade aparece que estava gravado.  podem me dizer se no meu código esta faltando alguma coisa?

```
                        <label for="UnidadeFederativa">Unidade Federativa</label>

                        <select class="form-control" ng-model="usuario.IdUnidadeFederativa" ng-init="consultarUnidadeFederativas()" ng-change="consultarCidades(usuario.IdUnidadeFederativa)">

                            <option value="{{f.IdUnidadeFederativa}}" ng-repeat="f in unidadeFederativas"
                                    ng-selected="f.IdUnidadeFederativa == usuario.IdUnidadeFederativa">
                                {{f.Sigla}}
                            </option>

                        </select>



                        <!--Cidadessss-->
                        <label>Selecione a Cidade:</label>
                        <select class="form-control" ng-model="usuario.IdCidade" ng-init="consultarCidades()" ng-change="consultarBairrosParametros(usuario.IdCidade)">

                            <option value="{{c.IdCidade}}" ng-repeat="c in cidades"
                                    ng-selected="c.IdCidade == usuario.IdCidade">
                                {{c.Nome}}
                            </option>
                        </select>
```

Comment: Tenta usar o select com ng-options, tipo assim 
<selec ng-model="usuario.IdUnidadeFederativa" 
ng-options="f.Sigla for f in unidadeFederativas">  
</selec>

Comment: Bom dia amigo, acrescentei o ng-options  no select mais não carregou o nome da cidade salvo .

Comment: passa o código da controller para assim poder verificar melhor, quanto mais detalhes melhor

Comment: ok. vou postar .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Levyh Nunes, Postei o controller do estado e da cidade

//método para consultar todos

```
    public JsonResult ConsultarUnidadeFederativas()
    {
        try
        {
            var lista = new List<Unidade_FederativaConsultaViewModel>();


            Unidade_FederativaRepository rep = new Unidade_FederativaRepository();
            foreach (Unidade_Federativa f in rep.Consultar())
            {
                var model = new Unidade_FederativaConsultaViewModel();
                model.IdUnidadeFederativa = f.codigo;
                model.Descricao = f.descricao;
                model.Sigla = f.sigla;

                lista.Add(model); //adicionando na lista..
            }

            //retornando a lista..
            return Json(lista, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {

            //retornar erro..
            return Json(e.Message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }



    //método para Obter 
    public JsonResult ObterUnidadeFederativa(int idUnidadeFederativa)
    {
        try
        {
            //buscar 1  no banco de dados pelo id..
            Unidade_FederativaRepository rep = new Unidade_FederativaRepository();
            Unidade_Federativa f = rep.ConsultarPorId(idUnidadeFederativa);

            //retornando para a página..
            Unidade_FederativaConsultaViewModel model = new Unidade_FederativaConsultaViewModel();
            model.IdUnidadeFederativa = f.codigo;
            model.Descricao = f.descricao;
            model.Sigla = f.sigla;

            //enviando para a página..
            return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //retornar mensagem de erro..
            return Json(e.Message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```

//método para consultar todos as cidades

```
    public JsonResult ConsultarCidades(int? idUnidadeFederativa)
    {
        try
        {
            //criando uma lista da classe ViewModel..
            var lista = new List<CidadeConsultaViewModel>();

            //acessando a camada de repositorio
            CidadeRepository rep = new CidadeRepository();
            foreach (Cidade c in rep.ListaCidadeIdUnidadeFederativa(idUnidadeFederativa))
            {
                var model = new CidadeConsultaViewModel();
                model.IdCidade = c.chave;
                model.Nome = c.nome;
                // model.CEP = c.cep;
                //   model.UF = c.uf;
                //model.Codigo_Ibge = c.codigo_ibge;
                // model.IdUnidade_Federativa = c.IdUnidade_Federativa;
                lista.Add(model); //adicionando na lista..
            }

            //retornando a lista..
            return Json(lista, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //retornar erro..
            return Json(e.Message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }

    }


    //método  para retornar 1  pelo id..
    public JsonResult ObterCidade(int idCidade)
    {
        try
        {
            //buscar 1  no banco de dados pelo id..
            CidadeRepository rep = new CidadeRepository();
            Cidade c = rep.ConsultarPorId(idCidade);

            //retornando para a página..
            CidadeConsultaViewModel model = new CidadeConsultaViewModel();
            model.IdCidade = c.chave;
            model.Nome = c.nome;
            // model.CEP = c.cep;
            //   model.UF = c.uf;
            //model.Codigo_Ibge = c.codigo_ibge;
            // model.IdUnidade_Federativa = c.IdUnidade_Federativa;

            //enviando para a página..
            return Json(model, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            //retornar mensagem de erro..
            return Json(e.Message, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
        }
    }
```